# Modify phone mic audio buffer before sending it to call recipient on android?

Tags: android, audio

I have fair experience with C#/Java so I don't need any explanation when it comes to programming it. Just wanted to know which classes hold the information and which functions to hook?

Comment: This should not have been closed - the answer is "No" but the questions is legitimate and fully specific, in that if it were possible, an answerer would know which details to include.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in "Android" as Android merely specifies the routing of call audio, it never actually touches the data.

On many phones the in-call audio never even passes through the processor core on which Android runs.

There may be phones where it is possible to modify the software which handles the call audio, however that would be done well below the level of "Android" in areas of the software stack unique to the hardware and vendor, and inaccessible to an application unless a security bug were exploited or an unsecured platform developer phone used.

The one case in which you could do this with Android-level APIs would be if you built a custom VOIP calling application.

Comment: If you are able to mute the input audio then I'm sure you can twist it around. If not on SDK Level then hardware.

Comment: No.  Muting is an example of configuring the audio path, which is very different than getting your hands on the actual data to examine or modify..